# How to call afterRender handler function in nested foreach?

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js

I had foreach statement and used afterRender to call the function.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.keys(pricings()), as: '_propkey', afterRender: pricingTableRenderedHandler }">
```

During this iteration, _propkey was a single string. Then I had to change foreach statement to this :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data:  pricings(), as: '_propertykey', afterRender: pricingTableRenderedHandler}">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: _propertykey.states, as: '_secondarypropkey'}">
```

handler function

```
  self.pricingTableRenderedHandler = function (data, stateName) {
        var tableSelector = "#" + stateName.states.state.replace(/\s/g, '');

        hideEmptyTableColumns.hide(tableSelector);
        replaceEmptyTableCells.replaceBy(self.emptyCellValue, tableSelector);
  }
```

In case of old foreach, it received string in stateName parameter. Now, it receives an object that  looks like this.

```
[ 
"cropYear" : "2020"
"states": [
    {
        "state": "Tbilisi",
        "details": {
            "PriceHeaders": [
            
            ],
            "Comment": "TBi",
            "Pricings": [
            ]
        }
    }
    {
        "state": "Texas",
        "details": {
            "PriceHeaders": [
               
            ],
            "Comment": "dasdsa",
            "Pricings": [
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

]

I only need to take "state" property value.
I'm assuming that I need to call handler function in inner foreach but for some reason, I can not. Unless it is written in the first foreach, it does not get called.

Comment: Have you tried `afterRender: $parent.pricingTableRenderedHandler` in the nested `foreach` binding?

Comment: Yes. That worked. You can writing is as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` binding creates a new binding context for every element. If, within the template you pass to `foreach`, you need to access a property of the original context, you can access that using `$parent`.

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: { 
                  data:  pricings(),
                  as: '_propertykey'
                }">
  <div data-bind="foreach: {
                    data: _propertykey.states,
                    as: '_secondarypropkey'},
                    afterRender: $parent.pricingTableRenderedHandler">
    <!--                         ^^^^^^^^                          -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the function will be called with the current element (`$data`) as `this`. If your handler relies on `this`, you can use `$parent.methodName.bind($parent)`.